# Grouping JSON data on multiple keys and retaining the keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a flat JSON file that looks like this:

```
{"dataSet": {"dataTable": [{
    "id": "List1",
    "row": [
        {
            "pagenumber": "7",
            "pageversion": "HE; K12",
            "category": "3D Print - K12;HE",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "MakerBot - 10771",
            "Allocation": "0.500",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        },
        {
            "pagenumber": "7",
            "pageversion": "SL",
            "category": "3D Print - SL",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "AUTODESK - 10032",
            "Allocation": "0.500",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        },
        {
            "pagenumber": "10",
            "pageversion": "Apply to All",
            "category": "Secure Printers",
            "pagetype": "Brand",
            "PtrChild": null,
            "Allocation": "1.000",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        },
        {
            "pagenumber": "11",
            "pageversion": "Apply to All",
            "category": "Secure Printers",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "EPSON INK JET** - 10082",
            "Allocation": "0.200",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        },
        {
            "pagenumber": "11",
            "pageversion": "Apply to All",
            "category": "Secure Printers",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "EPSON INK JET** - 10082",
            "Allocation": "0.200",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        },
        {
            "pagenumber": "11",
            "pageversion": "Apply to All",
            "category": "Secure Printers",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "EPSON INK JET** - 10082",
            "Allocation": "0.500",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        },
        {
            "pagenumber": "11",
            "pageversion": "Apply to All",
            "category": "Secure Printers",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "LEXMARK** - 10151",
            "Allocation": "0.200",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        }
    ]
}]}}
```

I need to group the data by pagenumber, then by pageversion, then by PtrChild, then by Allocation, so that it looks like this when finished:

```
{"pages": [
    {
        "pagenumber": "7",
        "versions": [
            {
                "pageversion": "HE; K12",
                "category": "3D Print - K12;HE",
                "pagetype": "Product",
                "partners": [{
                    "PtrChild": "MakerBot - 10771",
                    "allocations": [{
                        "Allocation": "0.500",
                        "ads": [{"catext": "Text goes here"}]
                    }]
                }]
            },
            {
                "pageversion": "SL",
                "category": "3D Print - SL",
                "pagetype": "Product",
                "partners": [{
                    "PtrChild": "AUTODESK - 10032",
                    "allocations": [{
                        "Allocation": "0.500",
                        "ads": [{"catext": "Text goes here"}]
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pagenumber": "10",
        "versions": [{
            "pageversion": "Apply to All",
            "category": "Secure Printers",
            "pagetype": "Brand",
            "partners": [{
                "PtrChild": null,
                "allocations": [{
                    "Allocation": "1.500",
                    "ads": [{"catext": "Text goes here"}]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "pagenumber": "11",
        "versions": [{
            "pageversion": "Apply to All",
            "category": "Secure Printers",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "partners": [
                {
                    "PtrChild": "EPSON INK JET** - 10082",
                    "allocations": [
                        {
                            "Allocation": "0.250",
                            "ads": [
                                {"catext": "Text goes here"},
                                {"catext": "Text goes here"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Allocation": "0.500",
                            "ads": [{"catext": "Text goes here"}]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "PtrChild": "LEXMARK** - 10151",
                    "allocations": [{
                        "Allocation": "0.200",
                        "ads": [{"catext": "Text goes here"}]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]}
```

Running this:

```
var myGroupedData = nest(myCatalog, ["pagenumber", "pageversion", "PtrChild", "Allocation"]);
// Reorganize JSON data
function nest(collection, keys) {
    if (!keys.length) {
        return collection;
    }
    else {
        return _(collection).groupBy(keys[0]).mapValues(function(values) { 
            return nest(values, keys.slice(1));
        }).value();
    }
}
```

...gets the grouping right, but eliminates the Keys for each group:

```
{
    "7": {
        "HE; K12": {"MakerBot - 10771": {"0.500": [{
            "pagenumber": "7",
            "pageversion": "HE; K12",
            "category": "3D Print - K12;HE",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "MakerBot - 10771",
            "Allocation": "0.500",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        }]}},
        "SL": {"AUTODESK - 10032": {"0.500": [{
            "pagenumber": "7",
            "pageversion": "SL",
            "category": "3D Print - SL",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "AUTODESK - 10032",
            "Allocation": "0.500",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        }]}}
    },
    "10": {"Apply to All": {"null": {"1.000": [{
        "pagenumber": "10",
        "pageversion": "Apply to All",
        "category": "Secure Printers",
        "pagetype": "Brand",
        "PtrChild": null,
        "Allocation": "1.000",
        "catext": "Text goes here"
    }]}}},
    "11": {"Apply to All": {
        "EPSON INK JET** - 10082": {
            "0.200": [
                {
                    "pagenumber": "11",
                    "pageversion": "Apply to All",
                    "category": "Secure Printers",
                    "pagetype": "Product",
                    "PtrChild": "EPSON INK JET** - 10082",
                    "Allocation": "0.200",
                    "catext": "Text goes here"
                },
                {
                    "pagenumber": "11",
                    "pageversion": "Apply to All",
                    "category": "Secure Printers",
                    "pagetype": "Product",
                    "PtrChild": "EPSON INK JET** - 10082",
                    "Allocation": "0.200",
                    "catext": "Text goes here"
                }
            ],
            "0.500": [{
                "pagenumber": "11",
                "pageversion": "Apply to All",
                "category": "Secure Printers",
                "pagetype": "Product",
                "PtrChild": "EPSON INK JET** - 10082",
                "Allocation": "0.500",
                "catext": "Text goes here"
            }]
        },
        "LEXMARK** - 10151": {"0.200": [{
            "pagenumber": "11",
            "pageversion": "Apply to All",
            "category": "Secure Printers",
            "pagetype": "Product",
            "PtrChild": "LEXMARK** - 10151",
            "Allocation": "0.200",
            "catext": "Text goes here"
        }]}
    }}
}
```

How can I retain the keys and group on multiple keys?

I'm forced to use ExtendScript, so can't use Lodash beyond version 3.10.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works with ES5 and lodash 3.10.1. It's based on the props idea in [Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55874415/5157454).

The idea here, however, is not to remove the properties from the end object, but for each level to pick it's own properties after group, and if it's the last level, avoid grouping, and create an array from the properties.

```js
function nest(collection, props) { 
  var currentProps = _.first(props);
  var restProps = _.rest(props);
  
  if(_.size(props) === 1) {
    return _.map(collection, _.partialRight(_.pick, currentProps));
  }  

  return _(collection)
    .groupBy(_.first(currentProps))
    .map(function(values) {
      var item = _.first(values);
      var fields = _.pick(item, _.initial(currentProps));
      var collectionKey = _.last(currentProps);
      fields[collectionKey] = nest(values, restProps);
    
      return fields;
    })
    .value();
}

var myCatalog = {"dataSet":{"dataTable":[{"id":"List1","row":[{"pagenumber":"7","pageversion":"HE; K12","category":"3D Print - K12;HE","pagetype":"Product","PtrChild":"MakerBot - 10771","Allocation":"0.500","catext":"Text goes here"},{"pagenumber":"7","pageversion":"SL","category":"3D Print - SL","pagetype":"Product","PtrChild":"AUTODESK - 10032","Allocation":"0.500","catext":"Text goes here"},{"pagenumber":"10","pageversion":"Apply to All","category":"Secure Printers","pagetype":"Brand","PtrChild":null,"Allocation":"1.000","catext":"Text goes here"},{"pagenumber":"11","pageversion":"Apply to All","category":"Secure Printers","pagetype":"Product","PtrChild":"EPSON INK JET** - 10082","Allocation":"0.200","catext":"Text goes here"},{"pagenumber":"11","pageversion":"Apply to All","category":"Secure Printers","pagetype":"Product","PtrChild":"EPSON INK JET** - 10082","Allocation":"0.200","catext":"Text goes here"},{"pagenumber":"11","pageversion":"Apply to All","category":"Secure Printers","pagetype":"Product","PtrChild":"EPSON INK JET** - 10082","Allocation":"0.500","catext":"Text goes here"},{"pagenumber":"11","pageversion":"Apply to All","category":"Secure Printers","pagetype":"Product","PtrChild":"LEXMARK** - 10151","Allocation":"0.200","catext":"Text goes here"}]}]}};

var props = [["pagenumber", "versions"], ["pageversion", "category", "pagetype", "partners"], ["PtrChild", "allocations"], ["Allocation", "ads"], ["catext"]];

var myGroupedData = nest(_.flatten(_.map(myCatalog.dataSet.dataTable, 'row')), props);

console.log(myGroupedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an helper array for the wanted properties for every level and a last item for the different named children array and a method for pulling out used properties of the object for getting a cleaned object for the final pushing.

```js
var data = { dataSet: { dataTable: [{ id: "List1", row: [{ pagenumber: "7", pageversion: "HE; K12", category: "3D Print - K12;HE", pagetype: "Product", PtrChild: "MakerBot - 10771", Allocation: "0.500", catext: "Text goes here" }, { pagenumber: "7", pageversion: "SL", category: "3D Print - SL", pagetype: "Product", PtrChild: "AUTODESK - 10032", Allocation: "0.500", catext: "Text goes here" }, { pagenumber: "10", pageversion: "Apply to All", category: "Secure Printers", pagetype: "Brand", PtrChild: null, Allocation: "1.000", catext: "Text goes here" }, { pagenumber: "11", pageversion: "Apply to All", category: "Secure Printers", pagetype: "Product", PtrChild: "EPSON INK JET** - 10082", Allocation: "0.200", catext: "Text goes here" }, { pagenumber: "11", pageversion: "Apply to All", category: "Secure Printers", pagetype: "Product", PtrChild: "EPSON INK JET** - 10082", Allocation: "0.200", catext: "Text goes here" }, { pagenumber: "11", pageversion: "Apply to All", category: "Secure Printers", pagetype: "Product", PtrChild: "EPSON INK JET** - 10082", Allocation: "0.500", catext: "Text goes here" }, { pagenumber: "11", pageversion: "Apply to All", category: "Secure Printers", pagetype: "Product", PtrChild: "LEXMARK** - 10151", Allocation: "0.200", catext: "Text goes here" }] }] } },
    props = [["pagenumber", "versions"], ["pageversion", "category", "pagetype", "partners"], ["PtrChild", "allocations"], ["Allocation", "ads"]],
    result = data.dataSet.dataTable.reduce((r, { row }) => {
        row.forEach(o => props.reduce((a, [...keys]) => {
            var children = keys.pop(),
                temp = a.find(p => p[keys[0]] === o[keys[0]]);
            if (!temp) a.push(temp = Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })), { [children]: [] }));
            o = keys.reduce((p, k) => ({ [k]: k, ...p } = p, p), o);
            return temp[children];
        }, r).push(o));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it works amazingly. I had similar idea of using reduce but mine was absolutely longer then yours.